# Visual Studio Express 2012. Could not create MVC4 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

It was working normally before deleting account model files from previous project. After deleting files, I tried to run previous project but it failed. I said OK and deleted previous project from the disk (not using IDE, but by myself). Now I am trying to create new project in this way:File->New project->C# project->Web->MVC 4 Application->Internet Application. It gets stuck on this message:

[image]

and showing this message:

[image]

What to do to solve this problem?

Comment: I had to re run the setup in repair mode to get this solve. This mostly happens if there are errors during installation or MVC template was not installed

Comment: Are you trying to create a project to a network drive?

Comment: Sippy, yes, I am trying to create project in network drive. This could make problem?